# How to get browser type and version from within an applet?

Tags: browser, applet

Is is possible to query the current browser from within an applet?

I would like to know if the current browser is IE6 or IE7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something for ya: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0160.html

Comment: This page is now deprecated. Use this one instead : http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-detect-browser-type-from-an-applet.html

Comment: @RealHowTo, feel free to update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[User-Agent detection](http://nerds.palmdrive.net/useragent/code.html) code is quite old (stops at IE6) but should be easily extended. Should be combined with R. Gagnon code pointed by Filip, for better detection of real browser (some browsers allows to alter user agent string at will).
You might be interested by the [List of User Agent Strings](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) too.

Comment: I made a proper lib out of my old code. It now stops at IE12 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For information, the User-Agent detection code has been updated with the latest browsers.