# How do I tell which web browser a Java applet is running under, from the applet?

Tags: java, browser, version

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get browser type and version from within an applet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380612/how-to-get-browser-type-and-version-from-within-an-applet)

I need to get the web browser version / vendor that an applet is running in.  I can get the Java version and the OS from the System properties, but I don't see anything similar for the browser.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/380612/how-to-get-browser-type-and-version-from-within-an-applet

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the answers to that question is basically saying "not easily".  One answer assumes you already have a user-agent string, and the other one is about figuring it out based on the applet context, and a comment on the linked site says "this doesn't work on Java 1.6." Oh well.

Comment: There is possibility to do so combining JavaScript+Java. It's easy to detect the browser with JS and it's possible to setup communication from Applet to JS..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Javascript and modify param values.

Browser info can be fetched using navigator object

few of the methods

```
navigator.appName
navigator.appVersion
navigator.userAgent
```

and pass those values into applet  tags dynamically,which are actual parameters of method in an applet.

a small but good example can be found here on integrating javascript and java applets.
http://www.ibiblio.org/java/course/week5/16.html

after which you can set values using following snippet.

```
<applet >

<PARAM id="browserAgent" name="browserAgent" value=""/>

</applet>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("browserAgent").value=navigator.userAgent;

</script>
```